# Overriding a property

Tags: c#

I'm trying to override a property in my program.
Here is basically what I'm trying to do :

```
class A { public int test = 7; }

class B : A { public int test = 8; }


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A test1 = new A();
        A test2 = new B();

       Console.WriteLine(test1.test);
       Console.WriteLine(test2.test);

    }
}
```

This displays 7 in both case when I'd like it to display 8 in the 2nd case....

I've tried virtual and override as well as new (public new int test = 8;)
But it doesn't seem to work

And yes I know I should use private and getters. I just want to know if it's possible ?

**Edit :** I'm not a native C# programmer so forgive me if i mix the terms (such as field and propertys)!

Comment: At first you must understand different between property and field.

Comment: Yes it is possible. To do it, use properties!

Comment: You *hide* a *field*. That's different from from *overriding* a *property*

Comment: I'm not a native C# programmer so forgive me if i mix the terms !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to override a property in my program.

```
class A { public int test = 7; }
```

The problem is that `int test` is not a *property*, it is a public *field*. Fields cannot be overriden.

Here is an example of overriding a property:

```
class A {
    public virtual int test {
        get {return 7;}
    }
}

class B : A {
    public override int test {
        get {return 8;}
    }
}
```

Here is [a demo of this code on ideone](http://ideone.com/KFMDsJ).

Answer (score 1):

`test` is a field, not a property. You must change it to a property and add the `virtual` modifier to allow it to be overriden in a subclass. You must then use the `override` keyword to override the value returned in class `B`:

```
class A
{
    public virtual int test
    {
        get { return 7; }
    }
}

class B : A 
{
    public override int test
    {
        get { return 8; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
A test2 = new B();
```

with this

```
B test2 = new B();
```

If you create test2 as A you call A methods

Comment: This is not the issue. This would be true is there were methods involved and he were hiding them, but that's not the case here.